# Sort NSMutableArray by another array content

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to sort a NSMutableArray by a NSArray content.

For example, the content of NSMutableArray (which contains NSMutableDictionnary) is :

```
{
    detail = "Al's legend text";
    image = "http://...";
    main = "Al's main text;
    section = "United States";
},
{
    detail = "Yumi's legend text";
    image = "http://...";
    main = "Yumi's main text;
    section = "Japan";
},
{
    detail = "Enrico's legend text";
    image = "http://...";
    main = "Enrico's main text;
    section = "Spain";
}, ...
```

For now, I know how to sort it by key, ascending or descending but what I need is the NSMutableArray be sorted by the following NSArray content :

```
{ @"Japan",@"France",@"United States",@"Uruguay",@"Spain", ...}
```

If someone can help me to figure it out. Big thanks !

Comment: What have you thought about? What have you tried? What did it do wrong? Show the code.

Comment: The fact is I just didn't find any solution to sort a NSArray by comparing key (@"section") with a NSArray object...

Comment: [tableViewArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                NSUInteger idx1 = [sectionOrderSort indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"section"]];
                NSUInteger idx2 = [sectionOrderSort indexOfObject:[obj2  valueForKey:@"section"]];
                return (idx1<idx2) ? NSOrderedAscending : (idx1>idx2) ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
            }];
This sounds like doing the job...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use sortUsingSelector:  this method of nsmutablearray array requires that you write a function that does your custom comparison.  Look at the documentation and it will show you how to use it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector:

Comment: Thanks Dancreek, but I'm a beginner in obj-c, and this is not helping me - Can't know how to code it in order to make the comparaison between the key and the nsarray order.